# Iterate through all filenames/urls in a webpage in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a webpage in Java, and I need to search the page for URL's and file paths, that could be relative, or absolute. (eg. ../../file.gif or http://hostname.com/file.gif). Not all of these will have html tags around then like `<a href>`, since some of the file paths may be embedded in some javascript.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Comment: If you've read any hits from Google for this, you'll know not to use regex for this, but instead to use an HTML parser such as JSoup. Trying to parse HTML with regex is like trying to drink soup with a fork. Just don't do it.

Comment: This might provide some insight:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java

Comment: If the tags are unreliable you might be able to treat the page as a text document and use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1806161/1343161