# Regex for finding mp4 in string

Tags: java, regex

I want to get all .mp4 URLs of this String using Regex.

Also I want to know how to get only the last .mp4 URL using Regex.

Thanks

```
contentType=application/x-mpegURL, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/pl/BjHU8aBCbOgZNzXQ.m3u8}, 

Variant{bitrate=0, contentType=application/dash+xml, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/pl/BjHU8aBCbOgZNzXQ.mpd}, 

Variant{bitrate=320000, contentType=video/mp4, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/320x180/YqZ72rzLj3VWVhy4.mp4}, 

Variant{bitrate=832000, contentType=video/mp4, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/640x360/A2vMgzo2ElpPP6TE.mp4}, 

Variant{bitrate=2176000, contentType=video/mp4, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/1280x720/j9xbNzRZqEbYs_2s.mp4}]}]";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2 Approaches:**

1. If you're sure the URL's will always begin with `https://` and will not contain a `mp4` after the complete URL is finished, then you can use
   `pattern = "https://.*mp4";`

   ```
   String[] arr = {
       "contentType=application/x-mpegURL, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/pl/BjHU8aBCbOgZNzXQ.m3u8}",

       "Variant{bitrate=0, contentType=application/dash+xml, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/pl/BjHU8aBCbOgZNzXQ.mpd}",

       "Variant{bitrate=320000, contentType=video/mp4, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/320x180/YqZ72rzLj3VWVhy4.mp4}",

       "Variant{bitrate=832000, contentType=video/mp4, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/640x360/A2vMgzo2ElpPP6TE.mp4}",

       "Variant{bitrate=2176000, contentType=video/mp4, url=https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/1280x720/j9xbNzRZqEbYs_2s.mp4}]}]" 
   };
   String pattern = "https://.*mp4";
   Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

   for (String line : arr) {
       Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
       if (m.find()) {
           System.out.println(m.group(0));
       } else {
           System.out.println("NO MATCH");
       }
   }
   ```
2. If not, **to Support all types of URL's** then change your pattern to what is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806161/1925997) with a little modification,

   ```
   String pattern = 
       "(((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~\\/|\\/)|www.)" + 
       "(\\w+:\\w+@)?(([-\\w]+\\.)+(com|org|net|gov" + 
       "|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum" + 
       "|travel|[a-z]{2}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?" + 
       "(((\\/([-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|\\/)+|\\?|#)?" + 
       "((\\?([-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" + 
       "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)" + 
       "(&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" + 
       "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*" + 
       "(#([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?\\b"+"mp4";
   ```

Output:

```
NO MATCH
NO MATCH
https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/320x180/YqZ72rzLj3VWVhy4.mp4
https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/640x360/A2vMgzo2ElpPP6TE.mp4
https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/822938952332144642/vid/1280x720/j9xbNzRZqEbYs_2s.mp4
```

Comment: The first approache will not work since my urls are in one single line string not in new lines or arrays. but the second approache works perfect thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Regex:**

```
https?.*?\.mp4
```

Literal `http`

Followed by an optional 's': `s?`

*Remove the question mark if they will all use HTTPS.*

Followed by as few characters as possible: `.*?`

Followed by an mp4 extension (literal dot) `\.mp4`

Comment: *This should be the accepted answer!* However, it would be helpful if you could provide some more information on how to exclude some Strings (like `jpg`) within the URL. i.e. I don’t want to match `<img src="https://image.jpg"><a href="http://video.mp4">`